# laravel : symlink storage in public not working " 404 (not found)"

Tags: laravel, storage, symlink

when I try to visualise my picture with this basic url on google :

> domain.com/storage/transports/picture.png

I get `(404) not found`.

(I don't have this error for a file outside the storage symlink in my tree picture and I can totaly see it without any problems, exemple :

> domain.com/logo.svg

I have used `php artisan storage:link` to create the symlink, so far I'm abble to store the pictures exactly where I want to with that controller :

```
public function storeTransports(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            session(['content'=>'content_transports']);

            $request->validate([
                'name' => [ 'string', 'max:255'],
                'picture' => [ 'required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg', 'max:2048']
            ]);

            if(Transport::where('name', $request->name)->first()){
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with('error_transports', 'Transport already exists');
            }
            else{
                if($request->hasFile('picture')){
                    $sanitized_image_name = strtolower(preg_replace("([^A-Za-z0-9])", "", $request->name)).'_'.time();
                    $image_name = $sanitized_image_name.'.'.$request->picture->extension();

                    Transport::create([
                        'name' => $request->name,
                        'path_picture' => $image_name
                    ]);

                    $request->picture->storeAs('public/transports',$image_name);
                }
            }

            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with('success_transports', 'Transport saved successfully');
        } catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with('error_transports',$e->errorInfo);
        }
    }
```

I can also visualize my pictures in my public folder :
[image: folder tree]

i've `rm rf public/storage` many times already

here is my configfiles.php :

```
<?php

return [


    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public'),


    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

I appreciate your help, I've been looking at all the stackoverflow talking about that for the past hour.

PS: I don't use vagrant.

Comment: This problem in local or on server?

Comment: on local definitly. i mean, i'm dev'ing on mac so far, telle me if i'm missing something.

Comment: Did you run it from php artisan serve? Please Try to run php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: I actually already did that but it didn't change much, what would you actualy type in to the url bar to see the picture tho ?

Comment: In my project, i just type http://localhost:8000/storage/folder/file.png . Maybe you can try to dd it with assets('stotage/folder/file.png')

Comment: you meant dd(asset('storage/transports/file.png')) ?

Comment: Yes i meant like that

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

i finally fixed my issue, as Matty10209 mentoned [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/storage-link-not-loading-image-after-symlink?page=1&replyId=781181),

"[...]When running "php artisan storage:link", Laravel creates an absolute path for the image to your local directory. Docker does not like this and wants a relative one, so it breaks the image link and you get a 404. You have to create the symlink manually[...]"

"[...] Go to docker and the CLI of your project container (should be at the bottom). Delete the current symlink you have created with Laravel, then navigate to the path you wish to create a new one. and run

> ln -s ../storage/app/public storage

[...]"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).